# SwiftUI run-time issue when using an environment object

Tags: xcode, swiftui, runtime-error

I've faced this issue on one of my old projects and I'm sure that there were no runtime issues back then: (current Xcode: 14.1)

The Style is global:

```
@main
struct TestingApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup { 
            TestView().environmentObject(Style()) // <- Here
        }
    }
}
```

Each page may has access to the style through the `EnvironmentObject`:

```
struct TestView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var style: Style

    public var body: some View {
        Text("Hello World")
            .padding(style.size.inputPadding) // <- Run-time issue on this line
    }
}
```

And the `Style` itself declared like this:

```
class Style: ObservableObject {
    @Published var size = Size()
}

struct Size {
    @ScaledMetric(relativeTo: .body) var inputPadding: CGFloat = 8
}
```

I'm getting this run-time issue:

> Accessing Environment<CGFloat>'s value outside of being installed on a View. This will always read the default value and will not update.

and

> Accessing Environment<DynamicTypeSize>'s value outside of being installed on a View. This will always read the default value and will not update.

Can someone explain what is happening and why this is considered as **ACCESSING** value **OUTSIDE** of being installed on a `View` ?

Answer (score 1):

They key part of the issue is where the wrapper is "installed"

```
@ScaledMetric
```

Doesn’t work in a regular `struct` because it conforms to `DynamicProperty`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/scaledmetric

```
DynamicProperty
```

> The view gives values to these properties prior to recomputing the view’s body.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/dynamicproperty

Your `Size` `struct` isn’t a `View` so it can’t get values. In prior versions you would get an initial value and some updates but it was a bug, SwiftUI just started warning about the issue.

This is why most SwiftUI wrappers only work in views.

If you remove the wrapper from the `Size` `struct` the warnings will go away.

Comment: Removing the wrapper is like wiping the question. So how can I have a dynamic-sized property inside a style class? Because it is **accessed** from a view body.

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini the question is "Can someone explain what is happening and why", removing the wrapper is just a confirmation of the reason why. "how can I have a dynamic-sized property" is a second question. Maybe loading "reference" scaled values at the top of the app could be a workaround, using dependency injection to keep scaled values updated. There is no "clean" way to do it, a `View` would have to share the information somehow. View>Style>Size

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini Also, I want to highlight that the issue isn't the accessing it is the "installation". "Accessing Environment<CGFloat>'s value outside of being **installed** on a View"

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini I was thinking. If `Size` doesn't change much you could use a `static` variable to initialize in the `TestView` `@ScaledMetric(relativeTo: .body) var inputPadding: CGFloat = Style.Size.inputPadding`